# Reference the location of a cell that is referenced by another cell

Tags: excel, reference, cell, offset, excel-indirect

I am posting this question because I had a hell of a time trying to find the answer myself.

Basically I have a cell that references a cell that references another cell with some data in it. For example, `A3=A2` and `A2=A1` and cell `A1` contains the text `Hello`. So cell `A2` and `A3` also contain the same text. See picture below:

[image]

But let's say I actually want cell `A3` to show data relative to the cell position that `A2` is pointing to (Remember `A3=A2`). I need to use the `OFFSET` function to do this and one would think that `A3=OFFSET(A2, 0, 1)` might work ([click here to see how OFFSET works](https://support.office.com/en-za/article/OFFSET-function-c8de19ae-dd79-4b9b-a14e-b4d906d11b66)). But `OFFSET` does not work by itself. It would return the data from the cell to the right of cell `A2` (shown below), instead of realizing that `A2` points to `A1` and then returning the data to the right of `A1`.

[image]

So how then do we get cell `A3=B1`, indirectly, by going through cell `A2`?

Comment: This may be more compicated than you seem to think, and will vary greatly based on what the formula is in A2. For example, if A2 is a vlookup, you can use MATCH to find the VLOOKUP-ed index key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to use a combination of functions, one of which is `INDIRECT`. [click here to see how INDIRECT works](https://support.office.com/en-ZA/article/INDIRECT-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261). So in order to use `INDIRECT` we need the text found in cell `A2`. The `FORMULATEXT` function ([more info](https://support.office.com/en-ZA/article/formulatext-function-0a786771-54fd-4ae2-96ee-09cda35439c8)) will extract `=A1` from cell `A2` when used like so in cell `A3`:

`A3=FORMULATEXT(A2)`, shown below:

[image]

Now we just need to strip off the `=` from the text so that we have an actual text reference that `INDIRECT` can use. You can do this using either the `RIGHT` or `MID` functions ([right](https://support.office.com/en-ZA/article/right-function-c02a18a8-b224-437e-aaba-1b785c6c61bf), [mid](https://support.office.com/en-ZA/article/mid-function-230833b1-28e7-4ef8-9286-eba06a3c29ad)) in combination with the `LEN` function ([length](https://support.office.com/en-ZA/article/LEN-function-038f2e0d-57d3-4f35-ae74-9a79d66e8fc2)). You need `LEN` if the number of rows in your sheet goes from single digit numbers into double digits, and so on. You also need to pass in the `FORMULATEXT` function again so it can compute the length of the text `=A1`. If you don't, it will compute the length of `Hello`. You also need to be aware that `LEN()-1` is the correct length you need, since you are throwing away the `=` from the text.

For example: `A3=RIGHT(FORMULATEXT(A2),LEN(FORMULATEXT(A2))-1)` giving us:

[image]

Put it all together and you can `OFFSET` the cell that `A2` references from `A3` with `INDIRECT` like so:

`A3=OFFSET(INDIRECT(RIGHT(FORMULATEXT(A2),LEN(FORMULATEXT(A2))-1)),0,1)`

[image]